# Why is .NET 3.0 not enabled on Windows Server 2008 by default?

Tags: windows, .net-framework

Windows Server 2008 comes with .NET 2.0 and .NET 3.0. Why is .NET 3.0 not enabled by default?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows Server can be used in various roles that may not require .NET, e.g. File Server, DHCP, etc. Enabling it means there's a larger attack surface area and you need to apply security patches to it, which may require server restarts, which are not fun on a production server. It's a good idea to install only things that you actually need, and since everybody won't need .NET 3.0, it's not enabled by default.

A good question also is why is .NET 2.0 enabled by default. I'm not that familiar with Windows Server 2008 and what it has enabled by default. If .NET 2.0 is enabled by default, it might be that some Windows component uses it.